# Iterative version of this recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, iteration

I have a function that is defined in this way:

> `F(n) = n` **`if n<=3`**
>
> `F(n) = F(n-1) + 2 * F(n-2) + 3 * F(n-3)` **`if n>3`**

Now, I've written it as a recursive function and it works fine.
I'm trying to write it as an iterative function but i cant seem to make it happen.

The output should be, for example:

```
print(FRec(5))  =>     22
print(FRec(10)) =>   1657
print(FRec(15)) => 124905
```

Any tips?

Here is my recursive implementation:

```
def FRec(n):
    if(n <= 3):
        return n
    if(n > 3):
        return FRec(n - 1) + 2 * FRec(n - 2) + 3 * FRec(n - 3)
```

Comment: These are the examples taken from the worksheet and the exact output from the recursive function.

Comment: Ah, no, my reading skills are mucked up. I'll edit your post to avoid this mistake for others.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The sum isn't F(n-1) + F(n-2) + F(n-3), it's F(n-1) + 2F(n-2) + 3F(n-3). 1*3 + 2*2 + 3*1 = 10 and 1*10 + 2*3 + 3*2 = 22.

Comment: See, this is why including your own code is important. It gives me to more places to check my assumptions against ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is keep the last 3 results:

```
from collections import deque

def F_iter(n):
    if n <= 3:
        return n
    prev = deque([1, 2, 3], maxlen=3)
    for i in range(4, n + 1):
        result = prev[-1] + 2 * prev[-2] + 3 * prev[-3]
        prev.append(result)
    return prev[-1]
```

If a `deque` is not 'available' to you, then you can inefficiently replace that with some list slicing and concatenation:

```
    prev = [1, 2, 3]
    for i in range(4, n + 1):
        result = prev[-1] + 2 * prev[-2] + 3 * prev[-3]
        prev = prev[1:] + [result]
```

Demo:

```
>>> F_iter(5)
22
>>> F_iter(10)
1657
>>> F_iter(15)
124905
```

Comment: Thank you! But is there any way to do it without deque?
I'm just in the beginning of this Python class in college and our assignment specifically says not to use tools that we haven't covered yet.

Comment: You can use a list, then remove the first element and add a new at the end each time: `prev = [1, 2, 3]` and `prev = prev[1:] + [sum(prev)]`. That's just not as efficient as a double-ended queue.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately we have yet to cover lists too. But i got the general idea and I'll try to translate it to something that satisfies my single minded instructor.

Comment: Then you could use three variables: `Fminus1, Fminus2, Fminus3 = 3, 2, 1` and `result = Fminus1 + 2 * Fminus2 + 3 * Fminus3` and `Fminus1, Fminus2, Fminus3 = result, Fminus1, Fminus2` and `return Fminus1` (untested).

Comment: Great answer Martijn. Very nice that it (the version with the `deque`) scales to arbitrarily deep recursion without needing to create a variable for each step.

Comment: Martjin, the world needs more people like you. Thank you.